# create a variable to see date when model was run with dbt

Tags: date, variables, casting, dbt

I need to add to my dbt model a column which shows the current date when the model is run.

I have tried `{{ run_started_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}` by adding it directly to my model and also have tried on setting a variable called date and creating this piece of code ( `{% set report_date = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict("select dateadd(day,-1,current_date()) as col")["COL"][0] %}` ) but the problem is that the dates, as we are today at 2021-12-14, the result for this column is 1995 ( this is the substraction of `2021 - 12 - 14`). So, does anybody now a way to cast this variable to a date? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I think I know the secret now

Please remember dbt is a tool for code-generating-like

In your case, I guess you must to wrap your jinja code in a string quote

WRONG:

```
SELECT {{ run_started_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }} as YourColumn
--compiled: SELECT 2021-12-14 as YourColumn
--YourColumn=1995
```

CORRECT:

```
SELECT '{{ run_started_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}' as YourColumn
--compiled: SELECT '2021-12-14' as YourColumn
--YourColumn=2021-12-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you would like a timestamp in your desired time zone you can use:

```
'{{ run_started_at.astimezone(modules.pytz.timezone("America/New_York")) }}' as run_started_at_est
```

This would return a varchar field `2023-11-02 09:42:09.343605-04:00`

For list of available time zones see:

https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568